# Decrease ionic-input height

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have created an ion-input component.

Using the following html:

```
<ion-item mode="md" class="roundedInput">
    <ion-label position="floating" id="inputlabel">{{labelname}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input #form__input [type]="type" [(ngModel)]="value" [placeholder]="placeholder" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ion-item.md{
    --border-color: var(--carbon-200, #767575);
    --border-radius: 8px;
    --border-width: 2px;
    --box-shadow: 2px var(--carbon-400, #767575);
    --highlight-height: 0;
    --background: var(--coconut-000, #F1F0F0);
    color:  var(--carbon-200, #767575);

}


.roundedInput.item-has-focus {
    --border-width: 0px;
    --highlight-background: var(--secondary-500, #f0b601);
    ion-label {
        color: var(--secondary-500, #f0b601) !important;
    }
}
```

And get the this input:
[Input working correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RxjD.png)

Then I have tried to adjust the height and add the property height this way:

```
ion-item.md{
    --border-color: var(--carbon-200, #767575);
    --border-radius: 8px;
    --border-width: 2px;
    --box-shadow: 2px var(--carbon-400, #767575);
    --highlight-height: 0;
    --background: var(--coconut-000, #F1F0F0);
    color:  var(--carbon-200, #767575);
    height: 10px;
```

[the input is cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87fWH.png)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can adjust the `padding` of the input too.

Comment: If you font is 12px and your input height is 10px what would you expect to happen?